# Android - Simulate Back Button

Tags: android, button, back

When i press a button in my app, I need to return to the last activity.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Calling `finish()` from the activity you want to end should take care of this.

**Edit many years later:** This still works, but it's a bit of a heavy-handed approach. When I originally posted this, `Fragments` didn't exist, and (as several commenters have pointed out) this doesn't work quite the same way when there are `Fragments` involved. There are better approaches now if you're using `Fragments.`

Comment: No need to apologize, just happy to help!

Comment: This does not simulate the back button. If you are only using activities it is ok but if you are using fragments in an activity, this will close all the fragments with the activity together.

Comment: @tasomaniac Ah, interesting.  I actually posted this answer before `Fragments` existed so that's interesting to know!

Comment: @tasomaniac It seems getFragmentManager().popBackStack() does the job for fragments.

Comment: It also doesn't work when you've overridden the back button to do something else (like for highly customized layouts)

Comment: It also doesn't alllow for overriding transistions.

Answer (score 85):

Just for record: The described method doesn't do the same as the back button does in some cases, but you can call

```
this.onBackPressed();
```

or

```
getActivity().onBackPressed();
```

if you are in a fragment to achieve exaclty the same behaviour.

Comment: From what I can tell, this is the best answer.  Thanks.

Comment: This is the correct solution, but make sure you are on the UI thread or it won't work.

Answer (score 43):

when using fragments:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

or

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

if you are using android.support.v4.app package

Comment: It didn't affect (reset) the toolbar in my case ( I was using navigation menu and many fragments declared in mobile_navigation.xml ). But it does return back.

Answer (score 2):

This is for a situation where the same fragment may sometimes be the only fragment in an activity, and sometimes part of a multi-fragment activity, for example on a tablet where two fragments are visible at the same time.

```
/**
 * Method that can be used by a fragment that has been started by MainFragment to terminate
 * itself. There is some controversy as to whether a fragment should remove itself from the back
 * stack, or if that is a violation of the Android design specs for fragments. See here:
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901298/how-to-get-a-fragment-to-remove-itself-i-e-its-equivalent-of-finish
 */
public static void fragmentImplementCancel(Fragment fragment) {

    FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = fragment.getActivity();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    }
    else {
        fragmentActivity.finish();
    }
}
```

This code can be called to implement a Cancel button, for example.

```
    if (theButton.getId() == R.id.btnStatusCancel) {
        StaticMethods.fragmentImplementCancel(this);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can spoof a up button call on back button press:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    onNavigateUp();
}
```

Comment: The question is about to go back to last activity for the button click.