# How to remove fragment from the back stack?

Tags: android, compatibility, android-fragments

For example there is 3 `Fragments` in back stack. Smth like

Fragment1, Fragment2, Fragment3.

Fragment3 is the last added fragment to stack. Is it possible to remove Fragment2 only?

I found out that it's possible to remove Fr1 and Fr2 together, or Fr2 and Fr3 together, but not fragment from the middle of stack.

Dmitriy.

Comment: That's why it's a stack.

Comment: you can find the similar one here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901298/how-to-get-a-fragment-to-remove-itself-i-e-its-equivalent-of-finish