# Handling ActionBar title with the fragment back stack?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have an `Activity` where I load in a `ListFragment` and, upon clicking, it drills down a level and a new type of `ListFragment` is shown, replacing the original one (using the `showFragment` method below). This is placed on the back stack.

At the beginning, the activity shows the default title in the action bar (i.e. it's set automatically based on the application's `android:label`).

When showing the list for the next level in the hierarchy, the name of the item clicked on should become the action bar's title.

However, when pressing <kbd>Back</kbd>, I would like the original default title to be restored.  This isn't something `FragmentTransaction` knows about, so the title isn't restored.

I've vaguely read about `FragmentBreadCrumbs`, but this seems to require using a custom view. I'm using ActionBarSherlock and would prefer to not have my own custom title view.

What is the best way of doing this?  Is it possible without a load of boilerplate code and having to keep track of the titles shown along the way?

---

```
protected void showFragment(Fragment f) {
  FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, f);
  ft.addToBackStack(null);
  ft.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

In every fragment and every activity I change the title like this. This way the active title will always be correct:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Set title
    getActivity().getActionBar()
        .setTitle(R.string.thetitle);
}
```

There is some cases where onResume isn't called inside fragments. In some of these cases we can use:

```
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser) {
        // Set title
        getActivity().getActionBar()
            .setTitle(R.string.thetitle);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had no need to cast, or get the action bar (i.e. I just call `getActivity().setTitle(...)`), but this is a reasonable approach. Thanks.

Comment: -1. This approach is incorrect! According to Android Design guidelines, when switching fragments using Navigation Drawer, the Action Bar title should only change in the Navigation Drawer onClosed callback. Your approach will incorrectly change the title before the Navigation Drawer is closed.

Comment: @zyamys If you come with a better suggestion I'd gladly upvote it. This was the best answer I could come up with at the time.

Comment: @Warpzit - my solution to this problem was to not use the stock BackStack at all and implement my own. It was actually very simple and has other benefits, such as being able to save the state in Shared Prefernces and being able to restore the state cleanly. I still use the FragmentManager and FragmentTransactions of course. I represented the stack as java.util.Stack containing by Fragment Tags. I then serialize the Stack into Shared Preferences.

Comment: @zyamys That would also work but seems like more work if you ask me.

Comment: @zyamys I couldn't find a reference to this in the Android Design guidelines. But in any case, I find the answer here thoroughly pragmatic and I — and apparently the developers of the Google Play and Google+ apps — can happily live with the fact that the title changes a few hundred milliseconds before the drawer is closed.

Comment: This didn't work for me so I changed it to `getActivity().setTitle(R.string.thetitle);` and then it worked.

Comment: i have problem when i popback from next fragment to previous fragment, the on resume method of previous fragment is not call. how can i solve my problem.

Comment: @Ram in in that case it should work. But there is also an event for when a fragment has focus you could use.

Comment: And how to the set the right drawer item selected??

Comment: @caBBAlainB both fragment and drawer (fragment will be in an activity) so the activity should be able to get that info and set it accordingly, if my comments isn't enough you'll have to make a question about it :)

Comment: This solution might be hard to apply to a case where you are loading two fragments into the same layout. If both of them would set title then which one would be the correct one? Or one of them would only set the title but the other wouldn't? This would lead to a very hard to read and understand code. In that context the only viable solution would be to set title when adding/replacing fragments using FragmentManager and keeping Activity the main controller that knows what is being loaded and what title has to be set.

Comment: this works only if you replace the fragment during FragmentTransaction.
what if you add a fragment instead of replace ?

Comment: @K00lkaM I'm pretty sure resume is still called for fragments when they are added...

Comment: @Warpzit, i have checked it and its mentioned in many answers, adding 'B' fragment over existing 'A', dont call onPause,OnStop,OnResume of 'A'...
while replacing does! 

if you are not convinced, override each of this method and add logs and see it for yourself

Comment: @Kamlesh but you only need onResume to be called for 'B', I don't get why you care about the rest for this scenario... or Even care about 'A' as the title should be updated for the new fragment...

Comment: @WarpZit, correct OnResume of "B" will be called when launched, but the question is related to back stack. when you are going from A-> B, you change the title, but when you go back to A, as in the question "A" onResume wont be called to again change the title to original

Comment: @Kamlesh I had a similar issue with fragments in a tab layout. I ended up using public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) { inside the fragments.

Comment: @Warpzit I am too having the issue with managing title on back stack, while using tab layout, but setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) or onResume() is never called when i navigate back from fragment 'B' to 'A'.

Comment: @AshishNair hmm setUserVisibleHint should be called every time. Maybe it is never called with false (dismissed)?

Comment: @Warpzit Actually i am navigating to different fragments from single tab; For E.g. i have Fragment 'A' on tab1 and I navigate to fragment 'B' from 'A', so when i navigate back from B->A, neither onResume() nor setUserVisibleHint() is called.

Comment: @AshishNair Hmmm in my experience setuservisiblehint has worked in those situations. if you can't get anything out in logs either you'll have to figure another approach...

Comment: @Warpzit Ok thanks, will try to figure out another approach.

Comment: Don't forget to change the selection on the drawer back if you have it! ListView mDrawerList;

mDrawerList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

mDrawerList.setItemChecked(0, true);

Comment: @Maciej Pigulski You can use view pager, title can be shown on TabHost, or there is no need to manipulate ActionBarTitle at all. Each fragment should be provided title along with bundle in setArguments for close association.

Answer (score 29):

As the original answer is quite old, this might come of help as well. As the documentation states, one might want to register a `listener` to listen on the back stack changes in the hosting `Activity`:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
        new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                // Update your UI here.
            }
        });
```

Then, identify the situation in the callback method and set a proper title, without accessing the `ActionBar` from the `Fragment`.

This is a more elegant solution as the `Fragment` doesn't have to know about the `ActionBar` existence and `Activity` is usually the place that is managing the backstack so having it handled over there seems to be more appropriate. `Fragment` should at all time be considered only by its own content, not the surroundings.

More on the topic in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments).

Comment: The other answer is old, but I still find it the simplest and most pragmatic way of ensuring the title is always correct. As mentioned in my comment, you do not need to access the ActionBar directly. The solution here requires more code, but also doesn't help for your initial fragment, which normally does not get added to the back stack.

Comment: Also there is nothing wrong with accessing the actionbar from fragments. Google also provides api for changing menu items inside fragments.

Comment: After some time I came to a conclusion that both solutions are fine, it just depends on your use case, sometimes it will be more feasible to use onResume and sometimes a fragment manager listener. So all in all it is good to know your tools, so you can apply them adequately to your needs.

Comment: @Maciej Pigulski And then? We do not know anything about the context in this callback.

Comment: @caBBAlainB, context is being held in the hosting Activity's FragmentManager so you would have to determine the title doing some cumbersome checks on the manager - thus it is not great. Today I can't remember what was my reasoning here. I think this idea mostly comes from what is written in Android docs linked in this answer (paragraph above the listener snippet). Today I would rather go and use the accepted answer.

Comment: @MaciejPigulski ok but it seems there is some lack of feature from Google here. Strange.

Comment: @caBBAlainB Google leaves things undocumented and in an unsupported state all the time requiring devs to write workarounds and hacks that go against their own design guides all the time.  I would hardly call this instance strange.

Answer (score 11):

Let the controlling activity do all the work as follows:

Listen for backstack events (in onCreate() of activity):

```
// Change the title back when the fragment is changed
    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            Fragment fragment = getFragment();
            setTitleFromFragment(fragment);
        }
    });
```

Get the current fragment from the container:

```
/**
 * Returns the currently displayed fragment.
 * @return
 *      Fragment or null.
 */
private Fragment getFragment() {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    return fragment;
}
```

Set the fragment inside the content view:

```
private void setFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
    // Set the activity title
    setTitleFromFragment(fragment);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: This is not "letting the activity do all the work" if you have implement some interface in every single `Fragment` so that `setTitleFromFragment()` can retrieve its title. None of which seems to fit the "without a load of boilerplate code" part of my question.

Comment: There is no mention of an interface in my solution, your activity can check the instance of the fragment and set the title based on that, thus letting your activity do all the work. All those methods are defined inside the activity.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds probably even worse from a design/separation of concerns/reusability point of view. Plus this redundantly changes the title twice for each fragment added to the backstack, since setTitleFromFragment method is called unconditionally in setFragment, I guess? Anyway, thanks, but I'll stick with the pragmatic and simple accepted answer :)

Comment: How does this sound "probably even worse from a design/separation of concerns/reusability point of view"? Please back it up with a valid argument?

You're letting the activity be a "controller" and set its own title based on its content. What if I want to use a fragment in multiple places, or have an activity with multiple fragments, and they all try to set the title.

Comment: Much helpful answer

Answer (score 7):

Warpzit is right. This also solves title problem when orientation of device is changed. Also if you use support v7 for action bar, you can get action bar from fragment like this :

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
}
```

Comment: +1 for support v7.  I think whenever an android answer is given the person answering should take support into account.  As of now, to reach 80% device coverage, you HAVE to go back to API 16.  In most cases that requires using the compat libraries.

Comment: i put your code in `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)` method and worked fine.

Answer (score 7):

It is best to let the OS do as much of the work as possible.
Assuming each fragment is properly named using .addToBackStack("title") then
you can override onBackPressed something like this to achieve desired behavior:

```
// this example uses the AppCompat support library
// and works for dynamic fragment titles
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    int count = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
    if (count <= 1) {
        finish();
    }
    else {
        String title = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(count-2).getName();
        if (count == 2) {
            // here I am using a NavigationDrawer and open it when transitioning to the initial fragment
            // a second back-press will result in finish() being called above.
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mNavigationDrawerFragment.getView());
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
        Log.v(TAG, "onBackPressed - title="+title);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I use a similar solution to [Lee approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33716380/5004910), but replacing `onBackStackChanged()` method instead.

First I set the fragment name when adding the transaction to the back stack.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_content, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(fragmentTitle)
                .commit();
```

Then I override the `onBackStackChanged()` method and I call `setTitle()` with the last backstack entry name.

```
@Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
    int lastBackStackEntryCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1;
    FragmentManager.BackStackEntry lastBackStackEntry =
            getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(lastBackStackEntryCount);

    setTitle(lastBackStackEntry.getName());
}
```

Comment: The problem with using the backstack entry name is that it doesn't handle configuration changes. An interesting and proper way to handle this issue would be to use setBreadCrumbTitle(int res) to save a title resource id, which you could use in the onBackStackChanged to set the title.

Answer (score 4):

Use Fragments method:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
```

It is called on every Fragment appearance, but onResume is not.

Comment: yes.. none of the answer are not saved my problem.. this works fine. It may not professional way.. but it little bit hacky.

Comment: @Bevor for this to work you need an options menu, you can activate it for a fragment by calling "setHasOptionsMenu(true);" in the OnCreateView(...) method of your fragment.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to make use of the android provided Interface OnBackStackChangedListener method onBackStackChanged().

Lets say we have a navigation drawer with 4 options to which the user can navigate to. In that case we will have 4 fragments. Lets see the code first and then I will explain the working.

```
    private int mPreviousBackStackCount = 0;
    private String[] title_name = {"Frag1","Frag2","Frag3","Frag4"};
    Stack<String> mFragPositionTitleDisplayed;

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ....
    ....
    ....
    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
    mFragPositionTitleDisplayed = new Stack<>();
}

public void displayFragment() {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new Fragment1();
            title = title_name[position];
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Fragment2();
            title = title_name[position];
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Fragment3();
            title = title_name[position];
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new Fragment4();
            title = title_name[position];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container_body, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
    int backStackEntryCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    if(mPreviousBackStackCount >= backStackEntryCount) {
        mFragPositionTitleDisplayed.pop();
        if (backStackEntryCount == 0)
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        else if (backStackEntryCount > 0) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mFragPositionTitleDisplayed.peek());
        }
        mPreviousBackStackCount--;
    }
    else{
        mFragPositionTitleDisplayed.push(title_name[position]);
        mPreviousBackStackCount++;
    }

}
```

In the code shown we have the displayFragment() method. Here I display the fragment on the basis of option chosen from the navigation drawer.The variable position corresponds to the position of the item clicked from the ListView or RecyclerView in the navigation drawer. I set the actionbar title accordingly with getSupportActionBar.setTitle(title), where the title stores the appropriate title name.

Whenever we click the item from nav drawer a fragment is displayed depending on the item clicked to the user. But on the back end side this fragment is added to the backstack and the method onBackStachChanged(), gets hit. What I have done is that I have created a variable mPreviousBackStackCount and initialized it to 0. I have also created an additional stack which will store the action bar title names.  Whenever I add a new fragment to the backstack, I add the corresponding title name to my created stack. On the opposite side whenever I press the back button onBackStackChanged() is called and I pop the last title name from my stack and set the title to the name derived by the peek() method of the stack.

Example:

Lets say our android backstack is empty:

Press Choice 1 from nav drawer:
onBackStachChanged() is called and the Fragment 1 is added to android backstack, backStackEntryCount is set to 1 and Frag1 is pushed to my stack and size of mFragPositionTitleDisplayed becomes 1.

Press Choice 2 from nav drawer:
onBackStachChanged() is called and the Fragment 2 is added to android backstack, backStackEntryCount is set to 2 and Frag2 is pushed to my stack and size of mFragPositionTitleDisplayed becomes 2.

Now we have 2 elements both in the android stack and my stack. When you press back button onBackStackChanged() is called and the value of backStackEntryCount is 1. The code enters the if part and pops out the last entry from my stack. So, the android backstack has only 1 fragment - "Fragment 1" and my stack has only 1 title - "Frag1". Now I just peek() the title from my stack and set the action bar to that title.

Remember: To set the action bat title use peek() and not pop() else your application will crash when you open more than 2 fragments and try to go back by pressing back button.

Comment: This is a ridiculous amount of code (especially compared to the accepted answer), and ignores my requirements in the question, i.e. to implement this without a load of boilerplate code and without having to keep track of the titles shown.

Comment: Yeah, well its your problem if you dont want excessive code. You got to compromise somewhere. Moreover the only important part in the code is OnBackStackChanged().

Answer (score 1):

You can Solve with onKeyDown!
I have a bool 
mainisopen=true <-- MainFragment is Visible
other Fragment mainisopen=false

and here is My Code:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && mainisopen == false) {
        mainisopen = true;
        HomeFrag fragment = new HomeFrag();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmet_cont, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_home).setChecked(true);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        this.setTitle("Digi - Home"); //Here set the Title back
        return true;
    } else {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && mainisopen == true) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Wollen sie die App schliessen!");
            builder.setCancelable(true);

            builder.setPositiveButton("Ja!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Nein!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Applikation wird fortgesetzt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();

            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://medium.com/@elye.project/puzzle-fragment-stack-pop-cause-issue-on-toolbar-8b947c5c07c6) my solution is adding this code to MainActivity onCreate method(): and changing actionbar title

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.My_Container_1_ID);
        currentFragment.onResume();
    }
});
```

and changing actionbar title in fragment's onResume() method

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    ActionBar actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
    if(actionBar!=null) {
        actionBar.setTitle("Fragment Title");
        actionBar.setSubtitle("Subtitle");
    }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

To update the actionbar title on back press. Just simply put

**getActivity.setTitle("title")**

inside onCreateView method.

Comment: `onCreateView` is only called when ... creating a view. If you press Back and the previous activity/fragment is still on the stack, then this method will not be called.