# Android Change App Icon Title

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have a single activity controlling many fragments. When i perform certain fragment transactions I add the transaction to the back stack and enable the app icon in the action bar to navigate up, i.e., `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`. However, I'd like to change the text alongside the app icon (currently defaulting to the app name) at run time to provide the user with a better indication of where they are located in the app. Any ideas of how this can be done?

Comment: Have you tried the activity setTitle() method?

Comment: That's it - d'oh! I'll mark as correct if you'd like to post one line answer - setTitle("Title").

Comment: 'Tis done. +1 to Fllo as well since that's useful info too in relation to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
setTitle("title text")
```

...within an Activity to change the text shown in the title bar next to the icon.

Answer (score 4):

Two ways, dynamically:

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setTitle("Title");
bar.setSubtitle("subtitle");
```

In manifest.xml:

```
 <application
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

In Fragment:

```
(FragmentActivity) getActivity()).getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title);
```

There is a lot of answers on that, try to do some researches to take these tricks, see: [Handling ActionBar title with the fragment back stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13473186/2668136)