# How to handle activity's title with fragments changing

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onkeydown

I have a single `Activity` app with a lot of fragments. How can I change the `ActionBar` title from activity, even when i press the back button and I return on the previous  `fragment`?
My fragments are being displayed on screen with (It's Scala language)

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment).addToBackStack(FourMeApp.discussion_backStack).commitAllowingStateLoss()
```

EDIT: I know how to set title on `Activity ActionBar`, I am asking about HOW to handle the title when user return to the last fragment with back button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23238212/3831557)

As per it you can addOnBackStackChangedListener in your activity and update your title here.

for HoneyComb and up i.e. Android 3.x and up

```
getActionBar().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
 new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
   public void onBackStackChanged() {
      // Update your UI here.
   }
});
```

or for Android 3.x and lower

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
   new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
     public void onBackStackChanged() {
       // Update your UI here.
     }
 });
```

Comment: I know how to set the title. I don't know when to set it if i sequentially change my activity with - for example - 5 sequential fragment. in onCreateView method i setTitle, ok. But if i press the back button i return to the previous fragment without the old title.