# why Actionbar title keep displaying the backstack title on hardware back button pressed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm trying to change the title of activity, where i'm going to the activity from the fragments, so when i click on the hardware back button the title doesn't chnage to the one that i have provided in that activity i.e

```
this.setTitle("Something");
```

I have also tried

```
setTitle("Something");
```

**Update**

When i use the below mentioned code i run into a problem where the title that i assign in the mainActivity stay in all the pages, hence in the frgament `getActivity().setTitle("");` seems to be useless in this case, so instead of changing everywhere the title using the below mentioned code i.e changing the actionbar title using `getsupportactionbar.settitle("")`, is there an easy way to do.

By any means can i know if an activity has came from the `system back button` back state or not?

Comment: Have you set `ActionBar#setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)` ? If not the title will probably not show up.

Comment: nope this did not work as well

Comment: You can't use `setTitle` on the `Activity` - You need to use below answer together with `ActionBar#setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)`.

Comment: I tried the same that you have given, and it has the same flaw i.e once i use that the same title is set to all the pages where i have specified title for each pag

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472258/handling-actionbar-title-with-the-fragment-back-stack

Comment: Well, I assure you there isn't a flaw in how we're telling you to do it. The only flaw is that you don't understand the solutions apparently. Don't down-vote them - it's not the answers that doesn't work.
If you're using Android Studio, create a new project and use the `Navigation Drawer Activity` template. Then look into the `MainActivity` class and see how the title is changed when different `Fragments` are attached to the contentview.

Comment: first thing i don't have enough credit to `downvote` people you should know that and the thing is that you don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle this situation with **onResume()** method

```
//...
@Override
onResume(){
   super.onResume();
   this.getActionBar().setTitle("Something");
}
```

ı think, that will help you.

Comment: if you didnt finish your activity after onBackPress method onResume will execute, why did not you accept?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setTitle("My Title");
    ab.setSubtitle("sub-title"); 
  }
```

**EDIT:**

For SupportActionBar use:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

**EDIT2:**

I use this to set Title from every fragment

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Set the title
    getActivity().getActionBar() //getSupportActionBar()
        .setTitle(R.string.fragment_title);
}
```

Comment: i'm using the support action bar so is the same going to work for me?

Comment: The problem with this is that the same title is being implemented to all other fragments that i have

Comment: well this solution did not help me

Comment: What do you mean with "being implemented to all other fragments"?

Comment: it simply means the title that i have given using your code in the activity won't let me change the title for other fragments

Answer (score 0):

If you always add your fragment to backstack when changing, then backpress can be override as follows to always get your previous fragment's title:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int T= getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        finish();
    }
    else if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
        finish();
    }
    else {
        String tr = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(T-2).getName();
        setTitle(tr);
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are occured this in Kotlin just remove Label from destination in Your navigation graph.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
getSupportActionbar().setTitle("Your Title")
```

You have to call this whenever you want to change your title.

If you are switching between fragments call the method again and switch it back to your old title.