# Fragment with MapView is never removed from FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mapview

I have a `Fragment` with `MapView` in it. I add `Fragment` to container with following code:

```
    Fragment fragment = new MyLocationFragment()
    String tag= fragment.getClass().getName();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left,
            R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, tag);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
```

Now when user presses back, this `Fragment` is supposed to be removed from `FragmentManager`. But if execute this code :

```
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MyLocationFragment.class.getName());
```

It never returns `null`, even if I replace other fragments in same container. What can I do to remove `Fragment` from `FragmentManager`? Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Anyone has any idea about when Fragments should be removed from FragmentManager?

Comment: It's supposed to be removed after it gets destroyed. Fragment with MapView gets destroyed, but never removed from FragmentManager, really strange!

Comment: But where is your remove line in your code??

Comment: It gets removed when Back is pressed as it's transaction is added to backStack.

Comment: So its like `transaction.remove(fragment)`??

Comment: Fragment automatically gets removed from FragmentManager on Back key press if FragmentTransaction was added to backStack.

Answer (score 0):

> When an activity is destroyed, its `FragmentManager`saves out its list of fragments. When the activity is recreated, the new `FragmentManager` retrieves the list and recreates the listed fragments to make everything as it was before.
>
> *[Refer to book "Android Programming The Big Nerd Ranch Guide"  P150]*

So your should remove fragment from fragmentmanager.
Refer to this Q&A [Remove old Fragment from fragment manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474584/remove-old-fragment-from-fragment-manager)

Your question maybe **duplicate** with this[How to get a Fragment to remove itself, i.e. its equivalent of finish()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901298/how-to-get-a-fragment-to-remove-itself-i-e-its-equivalent-of-finish)