# removing fragment from backstack

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, fragment-backstack

I want to remove fragment from backstack in the following situations

1. activity1-->fragment 1-->fragment
2. activity1-->fragment 1-->activity2

in both cases on back should return to activity1 skipping fragment1.
how can i achieve this.code sample would be helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing a Fragment from the back stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033019/removing-a-fragment-from-the-back-stack)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a Fragment to remove itself, i.e. its equivalent of finish()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901298/how-to-get-a-fragment-to-remove-itself-i-e-its-equivalent-of-finish)