# Button calles main activity from within the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I 've added a button to the menu which is suppose to take me from the fragment to the main activity but I don't now how to implement it?

I put a switch statement inside onOptionsItemSelected. 
 Fragment wehre I will call main activity:

```
  public class DetailFragment extends Fragment
     implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

     //Fragment detailFragment= new Fragment(this);

     // callback methods implemented by MainActivity
     public interface DetailFragmentListener {
      void onContactDeleted(); // called when a contact is deleted

      // pass Uri of contact to edit to the DetailFragmentListener
     void onEditContact(Uri contactUri);
     }

     private static final int CONTACT_LOADER = 0; // identifies the Loader

     private DetailFragmentListener listener; // MainActivity
     private Uri contactUri; // Uri of selected contact

     private TextView nameTextView; // displays contact's name
     private TextView phoneTextView; // displays contact's phone
     private TextView emailTextView; // displays contact's email
     private TextView specialtyTextView; // displays contact's
     private TextView cityTextView; // displays contact's city
     private TextView chargeTextView; // displays contact's state
     private TextView noteTextView; // displays contact's zip
     private Button callButton; //Nuha
     private Button emailButton;
   private Button smsButton;

  // set DetailFragmentListener when fragment attached
   @Override
   public void onAttach(Context context) {
     super.onAttach(context);
      listener = (DetailFragmentListener) context;
    }

      // remove DetailFragmentListener when fragment detached
      @Override
      public void onDetach() {
      super.onDetach();
      listener = null;
     }

     // called when DetailFragmentListener's view needs to be created
      @Override
    public View onCreateView(
       LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true); // this fragment has menu items to display

    // get Bundle of arguments then extract the contact's Uri
    Bundle arguments = getArguments();

    if (arguments != null)
     contactUri = arguments.getParcelable(MainActivity.CONTACT_URI);

   // inflate DetailFragment's layout
    View view =
          inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

   // get the EditTexts
   nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
   phoneTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phoneTextView);
   emailTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emailTextView);
   specialtyTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.specialtyTextView);
   cityTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cityTextView);
   chargeTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.chargeTextView);
   noteTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.noteTextView);
   callButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.callbutton);//nuha
   emailButton=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sendEmailbutton);
   smsButton=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.smsbutton);
   // load the contact
   getLoaderManager().initLoader(CONTACT_LOADER, null, this);

   addListenerOnButton(view);//Nuha buttons

   Animation animation =   AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.pop_enter);//Animate details Nuha
   nameTextView.startAnimation(animation);
   phoneTextView.startAnimation(animation);
   emailTextView.startAnimation(animation);
   emailButton.startAnimation(animation);
   specialtyTextView.startAnimation(animation);
   cityTextView.startAnimation(animation);
   chargeTextView.startAnimation(animation);
   noteTextView.startAnimation(animation);
   callButton.startAnimation(animation);
   emailButton.startAnimation(animation);//till here
   return view;
   }

  // display this fragment's menu items
  @Override
  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_details_menu, menu);
  }

 // handle menu item selections
 @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
     case R.id.action_edit:
        listener.onEditContact(contactUri); // pass Uri to listener
        return true;
     case R.id.action_home:////home button
       //What should I put here ??
        return true;
     case R.id.action_delete:
        deleteContact();
        return true;
   }

   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
```

My mainactivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
  implements ContactsFragment.ContactsFragmentListener,
 DetailFragment.DetailFragmentListener,
 AddEditFragment.AddEditFragmentListener {

 // key for storing a contact's Uri in a Bundle passed to a fragment
  public static final String CONTACT_URI = "contact_uri";

  private ContactsFragment contactsFragment; // displays contact list

   // display ContactsFragment when MainActivity first loads
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

  // if layout contains fragmentContainer, the phone layout is in use;
  // create and display a ContactsFragment
  if (savedInstanceState == null &&
     findViewById(R.id.fragmentContainer) != null) {
     // create ContactsFragment


    //Nuha animation
     // add the fragment to the FrameLayout
    ///Nuha try animation
     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit,    R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit);
    contactsFragment = new ContactsFragment();

     transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, contactsFragment);
     transaction.addToBackStack(null);
       transaction.commit();



       }
       else {
     contactsFragment =
        (ContactsFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().
           findFragmentById(R.id.contactsFragment);
       }
    }

    // display DetailFragment for selected contact
    @Override
    public void onContactSelected(Uri contactUri) {
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragmentContainer) != null) // phone
     displayContact(contactUri, R.id.fragmentContainer);
    else { // tablet
     // removes top of back stack
     getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();

     displayContact(contactUri, R.id.rightPaneContainer);
       }
    }

    // display AddEditFragment to add a new contact
    @Override
    public void onAddContact() {
       if (findViewById(R.id.fragmentContainer) != null) // phone
     displayAddEditFragment(R.id.fragmentContainer, null);
       else // tablet
     displayAddEditFragment(R.id.rightPaneContainer, null);
         }

  // display a contact
  private void displayContact(Uri contactUri, int viewID) {
   DetailFragment detailFragment = new DetailFragment();

    // specify contact's Uri as an argument to the DetailFragment
   Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
   arguments.putParcelable(CONTACT_URI, contactUri);
   detailFragment.setArguments(arguments);

       // use a FragmentTransaction to display the DetailFragment
       FragmentTransaction transaction =
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
       transaction.replace(viewID, detailFragment);
       transaction.addToBackStack(null);
       transaction.commit(); // causes DetailFragment to display
    }

    // display fragment for adding a new or editing an existing contact
    private void displayAddEditFragment(int viewID, Uri contactUri) {
       AddEditFragment addEditFragment = new AddEditFragment();

       // if editing existing contact, provide contactUri as an argument
       if (contactUri != null) {
     Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
     arguments.putParcelable(CONTACT_URI, contactUri);
     addEditFragment.setArguments(arguments);
       }

       // use a FragmentTransaction to display the AddEditFragment
       FragmentTransaction transaction =
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
       transaction.replace(viewID, addEditFragment);
       transaction.addToBackStack(null);
       transaction.commit(); // causes AddEditFragment to display
    }

    // return to contact list when displayed contact deleted
    @Override
    public void onContactDeleted() {
       // removes top of back stack
       getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
       contactsFragment.updateContactList(); // refresh contacts
    }

    // display the AddEditFragment to edit an existing contact
    @Override
    public void onEditContact(Uri contactUri) {
       if (findViewById(R.id.fragmentContainer) != null) // phone
     displayAddEditFragment(R.id.fragmentContainer, contactUri);

       else // tablet
     displayAddEditFragment(R.id.rightPaneContainer, contactUri);
    }

    // update GUI after new contact or updated contact saved
    @Override
    public void onAddEditCompleted(Uri contactUri) {
  // removes top of back stack
  getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
  contactsFragment.updateContactList(); // refresh contacts

  if (findViewById(R.id.fragmentContainer) == null) { // tablet
     // removes top of back stack
     getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();

     // on tablet, display contact that was just added or edited
     displayContact(contactUri, R.id.rightPaneContainer);
       }
    }
 //
 }
```

Can you please help ?

Edit: This fragment is associated with the main activity.. I want to return to the main activity with the original fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question correctly, this is what you need to put in your switch statement,

```
Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
startActivity(mainActivityIntent);
```

brief explanation of the constructor of Intent

1. `getActivity()` returns the activity associated with the fragment.
   The activity is a context (since Activity extends Context).
2. `MainActivity.class` is the activity you want to return to.

Hope this helps! :)

-After you updated the question-

I think this is what you are looking for [How to get a Fragment to remove itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9387251/4382835)

Comment: Still nothing happens when I click the button.. It might be cause this fragment is associated with the main activity.. but how can I go back to the main fragment used in the main activity.. do I make sense? sorry still trying to learn fragments

Comment: -After you updated the question- I think this is what you are looking for [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9387251/4382835)

Comment: Thank your help. I've tried but I'm getting the activity main without the fragment I need. Is there away to re attach the original fragment after dropping the current one?

Comment: I don't know if it would be a wise decision, but if it works for you and if you want to preserve the state so much,why don't you use a [dialog activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog). Just a suggestion.

Comment: I solved this by calling the oncontactdelete function from the main activity. It might not be the best practice but this function does what I want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help any way appreciate it

Comment: glad I could help :D

Comment: @NuhaAbd If you really do appreciate the help you could at least accept the answer it doesn't take much effort from your side but surely makes me happy.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use this  in your itenselected option

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityName.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

where context is the fragment that you are using , and the next is the activity that you want to go .

Comment: I can't use context and even with get context nothing happen. Thnks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this.(inside fragment)

```
Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I couldn't use getApplicationConetx so I replaced it with getActivity.getapplicationContext()... and nothing happens when I click on the button  :(