# Android Multiple Fragment Callback Confusion

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to wrap my head around the order and process of removing and signaling events to the Activity from the fragments.

I am trying to just have one FragmentA which is a list of items, transition to FragmentB upon a button click which loads a form to add a new item, and then when FragmentB is done with the form, add that item into the list of FragmentA. (The Main Arraylist is stored in MainActivity).

Basically, I have one MainActivity which creates a FragmentA (which populates a list with items). I also have a FragmentB (which is a form that allows an item to be added to the list).

What I'm getting confused about is how to properly set up the callbacks. I understand how to implement the callback with just one Fragment ([using this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks) and [this tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18110614/1377650)) but my confusion is this:

Which order is the correct one (if any)?

1. MainActivity 'creates' (transitions) FragmentA, FragmentA then
   transitions to FragmentB. FragmentB then sends the callback (adding
   a new item) to FragmentA, and FragmentA signals to the MainActivity
   to add the item to the main list (callback 2). MainActivity then
   closes FragmentB. (I want to leave FragmentA open).
2. MainActivity 'creates' (transitions) FragmentA, FragmentA then
   transitions to FragmentB. FragmentB then sends the callback (adding
   a new item) to MainActivity. MainActivity then closes FragmentB and
   returns the state back to FragmentA.
3. MainActivity 'creates' (transitions) FragmentA, MainActivity then
   transitions to FragmentB when FragmentA signals a callback to switch
   fragments (close fragmentA or add it to the backstack). FragmentB
   sends a callback to MainActivity, MainActivity closes FragmentB and
   then reopens FragmentA.

Hopefully I explained it alright enough, but I know it is kind of confusing the way I worded it.

*Edit*

One last question, would the Activity end up "implementing" 15 different Fragment listeners if you had 15 different Fragments that needed callbacks? Just seems a bit excessive.

Thanks

Comment: 15 fragments, each with their own specific need for an interface does seem a bit excessive. If you did get to that point, then there may be a better approach through EventBus, perhaps, but still, you need to handle each one of those events processes in some way

Comment: As for the question, I like the simplicity of option 2, but that is assuming the list adapter is bound to the Arraylist in the activity class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just consider the `Activity` as a father and the `Fragment`s are his children who have dependency to their father, So let the children make their wishes and the sugar daddy decides what is good for his sweethearts!

Main advantage of this approach is consistency and modularity of your code, Actually they have a server-client relationship, `Fragment`s send their request and tasks are done by the `Activity`, Each element plays its role in a clean and simple way.

Don't worry about number of interfaces you have to implement, But remember why an `Activity` exists So you can easily realize `Fragment`s which should be managed with a specific `Activity`.

`BroadcastReceiver` and [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library are the other options for communication but not the best in your case!