# How to do simulate a touch, or back button, without doing it yourself in other app?

Tags: android

I think it's not possible, but reading other questions i had no clear.
If you don't understand the question, maybe this question from another user is better than my question: "Is it possible to make a application to touch in x,y on each 10 second and minimize it, but touching in x,y be continued?"

What i want to do, is a kind of bot, that clicks on back button, or do a touch anywhere, every "x" seconds.

But i read that is not possible to do in another app, so maybe like this guy asked, if i do it to click a key, but then minimize it and come back to the app i want ?

Comment: "Minimize".  What does that mean?

Comment: To simulate touch :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867059/android-how-to-create-a-motionevent.

To simulate back button : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6897844/2956344

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with MonkeyRunner. Some tips for touch [already has been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4730492/1780581). Also, you can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html).